# Concatenate strings to make Picturebox name

Tags: c#, string

i have lot of pictureboxes named this way: PBr1_1, PBr1_2, ... PBr1_9

I'd like to make loop

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (Textbox.Text[i].ToString() == "1"){ "PBr1_"+"i".Tag = "cb.png";}
        }
```

so `for i=0 => PBr1_0, i=10 => Pbr1_10.`

Example i have value in textbox: 0001011101 - then if value in textbox is "1" then i'd like to change picturebox tag.

How to automate this process, using for example loop "for"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your controls are on a WinForm (this) and the ones with that name are all pictureboxes.
If so, that's the way ----

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{ 
    if (Textbox.Text[i].ToString() == "1")
    {
        Control[] c = this.Controls.Find("PBr1_" + i.ToString(), true);
        if(c != null && c.Length > 0) c[0].Tag = "cb.png";
    }
}
```

Comment: Find returns array of controls

Answer (score 0):

You can put the picture boxes in to a `List<PicutreBox>` and iterate over the list.

```
var pictures = new List<PictureBox>();
pictures.Add(pic1);
pictures.Add(pic2);
//...


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     if (Textbox.Text[i].ToString() == "1") 
          pictures[i].Tag = "cb.png";
}
```

Dynamic variable names as in your example are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array (or list) that contain the picture boxes and use those within the for loop.

You can also use reflection but in my opinion it is best not to use that in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `WinForm` you can use [Control.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.80%29.aspx) method to locate a control by name

Once you have got the control you can easily change any property